# What does it mean by Resource linking failed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I am trying to make a Trivia app by following the Udacity course. I am getting resource linking failed error which I am not able to understand or resolve.[This is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jwNo.png)

In-App I am trying to connect navigation graph with Mainactivity as following, but it is giving resource linking failed error:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navHost="@navigation/navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try replacing your attribute "app:navHost" with "app:navGraph" and also make sure you are linking your graph to that attribute with correct file name.

Comment: Akash, your fragment is a default navigation host and it needs a graph with all fragment destinations. Those destinations will be added to navigation graph, now you have to assign that graph to the attribute "app:navGraph"="@navigation/graph_name" and this proper resource linking. This is same explained clearly in udacity lectures too. Also check the Android developer documentation for more explanation.

Comment: Thank You @Rajasekhar. I understood it completely.